# How do I tell that a MinION run has finished based on the files produced?

Tags: nanopore, minion

I want to automate some scripts which should run after a MinION run completes. Is there a file which is produced by MinKNOW which will enable me to tell that the run has finished?

Comment: Use rampart and just stop it once you've happy with coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just look for the presence of a file called "final_summary_*.txt" in the run folder. From [Matt Loose](https://twitter.com/mattloose?lang=en).